# How can I share a custom argument from a user's tsconfig.json to my custom plugin?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc

How can I share a custom argument from a user's `tsconfig.json` to my custom plugin?

To install a plugin we do:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-my-plugin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would love to be able to write something akin to:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-my-plugin",
        "foo": "bar",
        "options": ["verbose", "production"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

or even

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-my-plugin"
      }
    ],
    "foo": "bar",
    "options": ["verbose", "production"]
  }
}
```

I checked the [Intro to the TSConfig Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) without finding what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to read in their set options, it's probably easiest to parse a user's `tsconfig.json` using something like `fs` from Node.

```
const tsconfigDir = process.cwd();

fs.readFile(path.resolve(tsconfigDir, 'tsconfig.json'), 'utf8', (err, fileBuffer) => {
  try {
    const tsConfigJSON = JSON.parse(fileBuffer);
    console.log(tsConfigJSON["compilerOptions"]["plugins"]["foo"]); // bar
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  }
});
```

This appears to be more or less how eslint supports their custom options

- [The file watch uses fs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/6c3816b3831e6e683c1a7842196b34248803d69b/packages/typescript-estree/src/create-program/createWatchProgram.ts)
- The options parser [resolves the tsconfig directory](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/8377e6ea422ee2d52455da8955ff055e09c238d3/packages/typescript-estree/src/parser.ts#L141)